# Documentation suggest a number of changes

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

I am new to documentation, I was trying to improve upon some existing answers but there was a dilemma. Say I have 5 suggestions to be made on the same question, once submitted either they all are approved or rejected.

How can I make them as different suggestions so that if one is good not all are rejected.

Answer (score 2):

First things first: a bit of terminology. Usually, on Stack Overflow, there are *questions* and *answers*, both of which you can edit. On Documentation, however, there are *topics*, which contain one or more *examples*. When you edit any of the examples for a topic, the system combines your edit into one for the entire topic. This happens automatically, even if you submit additional edits after the first one, as long as your original changes have not been reviewed yet.

Now, on to your question…

When you submit changes, they have to be reviewed by at least two other users. In order to minimize the amount of work involved, changes to a single topic are combined into one. That way, in the best case, only two users have to review your edits, and either vote to approve or reject them.

Under your scenario, if you could submit 5 different changes for the same topic, there would need to be a minimum of 5 × 2 = 10 reviews, which is a lot more. Sure, some of them could be the same users who are doing the reviewing, but if they're spending their time reviewing 5 suggestions from you, that's 4 suggestions from other people that they are not able to review. Or time that they're not spending improving the site in other ways (making their own edits, answering questions, etc.)

It might be putting it rather harsh, but if the system did allow you to do this and I saw someone doing it, I would see it as spamming a bunch of unnecessary edits. I'd consider it abusive behavior, and flag it so that a moderator could put a stop to it. I therefore *strongly oppose* this feature request.

Please only submit *good* edits. If you're uncertain about the quality of a change, just don't make it. (Consider adding an "improvement request" instead, so someone else who is more confident can make the changes.) Have respect for other people's time and efforts, too.